# List of all repositories from a private organization in github

Tags: python, github, github-api

Here is what I need:

I want to retrieve the list of all repos in my private organization, get the list of teams for all repos and then get all members from every team.

I am trying to do that now using simple auth requests in python passing in http commands, but that is not giving me the full list of repos.

Has anybody done this before ? Any python modules with samples that I can try ?

Comment: Can you show us some code? When you say it's "not giving me the full list of repos", what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Since you're trying to fetch repos for an org, I suspect you're using this endpoint (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-organization-repositories). You mentioned that you're not getting the full list of repos; are you sure you're not getting trolled by pagination? https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: @jasonrudolph A+ "trolled by pagination" :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't take credit for that phrase. That's a @pengwynn original. I'm just hoping he considers this fair use. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you can do this pretty nicely with github3.py (`pip install github3.py`):

```
import github3

gh = github3.login("Jason", "Jason's password")
org = gh.organization("Jason's organization with private repos")
repos = list(org.iter_repos(type="all"))  # Or type="private"
```

Alternatively, if you're feeling adventurous (`pip install --pre github3.py` to preview 1.0.0 of github3.py):

```
import github3

gh = github3.login("Jason", "Jason's password")
org = gh.organization("Jason's organization with private repos")
repos = list(org.repositories(type="all"))  # Or type="private"
```

github3.py will handle pagination for you (as Jason mentioned in a comment on your question) which is why you might wrap the iteration of an organization's repositories in a call to `list`. github3.py generates them 100 repositories at a time (instead of the default 30) so you should get 100 of them quickly and then wait maybe a second for the next 100 to be requested.

Comment: This works pretty good. I was able to get through my original question.